# Nginx serving from a different location with SSL

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx, webserver

I have a webserver running Nginx. I have successfully managed to get SSL working with a Let's Encrypt Certificate, but whenever I connect to HTTPS, the webserver serves me the default index page for Nginx ([this](http://prntscr.com/dt5vsw)). I have been unable to find where this is coming from.

This is the server block I have in the config for the SSL:

```
##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+CHACHA20-draft:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

server {

    listen 139.59.163.228:443 ssl;

    server_name sulphate.me www.sulphate.me;

    keepalive_timeout 75 75;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/sites/sulphate.me.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/sites/sulphate.me.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE

}
```

I want to be able to redirect it to where HTTP is served from (/var/www/html/), and also find out where this is coming from, since I haven't touched any location blocks.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You must to specify `root` directive  inside `server` block. Or, if you have another `server` block for http - just move all content of this `server` block to http one.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise it was this simple! All working now :)